# Mysql not equal

Tags: mysql

Hi I am having a mysql query

```
select balance (decimal) from table_name 
where balance != 0.00
```

I still get zero balances returned in my query. I have tried "0.00" and few other combinations which don't work. I tried like balance > 0.00 which returns all balances > 0 and excludes zero balances. When I try < 0.00, it returns balances with balance of 0.00. I am very very confused by this behaviour.

I come from MS-SQL background and hence I am not up to speed with MYSQL and hence this cry for help....

Comment: What is `select balance (decimal)` supposed to do?  I don't think `balance` is a built-in MySQL function.

Comment: I meant to say balanace as one of fields on the table which is of type decimal

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what your after:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `balance` <> '0'
```

This will return all the rows where the balance is greater then 0. It returns a ResultSet

Comment: The question is after non-zero balances including negative ones

Comment: @vogomatix Sorry didnt realize, changed the above code to match.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to remove the 'decimal' in brackets from your select statement otherwise:

You can also try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `balance` NOT 0
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `balance` NOT IN (0)
```

These are just more ways one can use the 'NOT EQUALS TO' in SQL syntax.

Hope this helps or at least give you guidelines to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
> 0 ' Greater than 0
< 0 ' Less than 0
!= 0 ' Not 0 - including negatives
```

For this, I dont think there is any different between mssql and mysql..

> When I try < 0.00, it returns balances with balance of 0.00

Be aware that MySQL's numeric fields can be "unsigned", which means MySQL will remove the negative symbol before saving when storing the data.